# Entity Framework tries setting property to null when querying, after new navigation property is added

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I add a navigation property from `Customer` to `Purchase` (as a collection) in my Entity Framework project. The relationship already existed before, so no database migration is performed.

When I retrieve a non-empty set of `Product` - which also has a navigation property to `Purchase` (as a collection) - from the context, I get the following exception:

> The 'BrandID' property on 'BrandedProduct' could not be set to a 'null' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Int32'.

Simplified code (all entities also have an ID property and a protected/public empty constructor):

```
public class Customer {
    // Adding this line causes the exception. Without it, everything works fine.
    public virtual ICollection<Purchase> Purchases { get; private set; }
}

public abstract class Product {
    public virtual ICollection<Purchase> Purchases { get; private set; }
}

public class BrandedProduct : Product {
    // This is the property that EF tries to set to null
    public int BrandID { get; private set; }

    public virtual Brand Brand { get; private set; }
}

public class Brand {}

// This works as a many-to-many relationship between Product and Customer
public class Purchase {
    public int CustomerID { get; private set; }
    public int ProductID { get; private set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; private set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; private set; }

    // Other properties...
}
```

The `Purchase` class has a composite primary key, so the following configuration is set up in the DataContext class.

```
public class DataContext : DbContext {
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder) {
        builder.Entity<Purchase>().HasKey(x => new { x.CustomerID, x.ProductID });
    }
}
```

Any idea why this could happen?

Comment: Just curious, are those your POCOs? Why do you have a private setter on your ID properties?

Comment: I am not totally familiar with the concept POCO, but these classes form a pure domain model without any references to Entity Framework. I use code-first migrations and all entities also have an ID. Database constraints are defined using EntityTypeConfigurations, like the last code block in my question, in a separate project. Private setters is just a preference I have, can that cause any problems? :)

Comment: If you are retrieving data through these classes, how would the ID's be populated if the setters are private?

Comment: Well, EF can actually populate a class with private setters. Lazy loading works as well - just make sure that the constructor is at least protected. For my domain, I use constructors and/or methods to mutate the objects.

Comment: You are right; I didn't know that. Thanks for the info. :)

Comment: Are you using a n-tier system?  
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596520281-01-20.aspx

Comment: @zackery.fix Yes, exactly.

Comment: is BrandId a Foreign Key in the BandProduct Table?

Comment: You need to use data transfer objects in your business logic. http://rlacovara.blogspot.com/2009/03/what-is-difference-between-dto-and-poco.html

Comment: @jpgrassi Yes. BrandID is a foreign key, and the property Brand is lazy loaded by EF with the entity with that ID.

Comment: `public int? BrandID { get; private set; }`  Use a `?` to make the `BrandID` nullable.

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is, I want Brand to be required. Therefore, I don't want BrandID to be nullable (even if that would be a workaround for this problem). And in the database, there are no null values for this field either - so I find it strange that EF tries to set it to null.

Comment: in your context is a whole object tree as it would be saved to the database. therefore, if no Brand is there, upon migrating the FK has to be set to null. I think in order to prevent this (as it can't be null) you get this exception. is the behavior the same if you populate the navigation property explicitly?

Comment: Right, if you need `Brand` to be required, it must exist in the database, otherwise EF will attempt to set the value to null (but its required, yet doesn't exist).  When EF makes it attempt at setting the null value, .NET prevents it because `BrandId` (ID for the FK `Brand`) is a non-nullable type.  Its logically impossible to meet both those requirements.

Comment: The exception occurs when I fetch `Product` entities from the Database Context. Since `BrandID` already exists as a non-nullable foreign key in the database, all `BrandedProduct` rows have a value pointing to an existing `Brand`. And the same query works when I don't have the `Purchases` navigation property in `Customer`... It's a tricky one :)

Answer (score 0):

In this example, it looks like the problem is due to `BrandedProduct` not having a primary key which is required by Entity Framework. It is attempting to figure out and set `BrandID` as the primary key, which has a private setter.

To solve this, just add the `[Key]` attribute or another `HasKey` to your configuration for a property with a public setter.